# Asyncio issues with Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have the bot as follows:

```
import discord
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', intents = intents, help_command = None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

async def status_task():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    while not bot.is_closed():
        await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.watching, name = "TEST!"))
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.watching, name = ".help for commands!"))
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

bot.loop.create_task(status_task())
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

With the await asyncio.sleep(10) the bot will not even run on my computer. Without it everything is fine, the loop even works. I have done pip install asyncio and a few other things I saw around here and nothing fixed it.

Comment: your code works for me on Linux Mint 20, Python 3.8.5. [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) is standard module and you should have it installed with Python (at least in newer Pythons) and you shouldn't install it with `pip`. Maybe you installed something different. For test you can add few `print()` in `status_task` to see if it really stops on `asyncio.sleep()`. Eventually you could use `@tasks.loop(seconds=10)` instead of `while` and `sleep` to run function periodically - doc [discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)

Comment: tasks was way better, works and is less lines. Thanks for the tip